# ...выполнить(,) что нужно

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, придаточное-предложение, дополнение

Известно, что с дополнением придаточное выделяется:

*Этого недостаточно, чтобы выполнить то, что нужно*.

А если дополнение убрать:

`Этого недостаточно, чтобы выполнить(,) что нужно`?

Будет ли придаточное, дополнением являясь, выделяться запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны такие **варианты** (без местоимения ТО):

(1) *Этого недостаточно, чтобы выполнить **что нужно*** (= нужное). **Устойчивый** оборот на основе придаточного, замена одним словом.

(2) *Этого недостаточно, чтобы выполнить, **что НАМ нужно*** (распространенное **придаточное**). В разговорном варианте **указательное** местоимение может быть опущено.

Здесь  **местоименно-определительное** придаточное, местоименная пара *ТО —  ЧТО*.